# Astropy, issue converting Heliocenric cartesian to RA/Dec

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to convert heliocentric Cartesian vectors to RA/Dec using Astropy.

I have the following output from the [Skybot](http://vo.imcce.fr/webservices/skybot/?forms=resolver) server for the position of Jupiter and asteroid Flora(8) at date 2019-10-11 00:00:

[image: Skybot output]
[image]

Using the Astropy coordinates package I can transform the heliocentric Cartesian vectors; Px, Py, Pz (x = -1.0394055704345, y = -5.1017277480665,  z = -2.1859827838526) to match the RA/Dec of the Skybot output (17 13 56.2541   -22 46 31.024).

```py
# Jupiter, Cartesian to ra/dec

from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

h = (-1.0394055704345,   -5.1017277480665,   -2.1859827838526) #Skybot Cartesian
Skybot_radec = '17 13 56.2541   -22 46 31.024'


helio = SkyCoord(x = h[0],   y =  h[1],  z = h[2],
                 unit='AU',
                 representation_type ='cartesian')

print('\nJupiter\nAstropy =    ', helio.to_string('hmsdms'))
print ('Skybot  =     ', Skybot_radec )
```

Skybot and Astropy give the same result:

```py
>>>
Jupiter
Astropy =     17h13m56.2542s -22d46m31.0237s
Skybot  =     17 13 56.2541  -22 46 31.024
```

However, trying the same process with the asteroid Flora results
in the ra/dec not matching:

```py
h = ( -0.217732049,  -2.230749006,  -0.848768038 ) #Skybot Cartesian
Skybot_radec = '16 25 19.6257   -19 37 54.618'


helio = SkyCoord(x = h[0],   y =  h[1],  z = h[2],
                 unit='AU',
                 representation_type='cartesian')


print('\nFlora\nAstropy =    ', helio.to_string('hmsdms'))
print ('Skybot  =    ', Skybot_radec )

>>>
Flora
Astropy =     17h37m42.0741s -20d44m27.5348s
Skybot  =     16 25 19.6257     -19 37 54.618
```

Why does it work for one case but not the other?

In response to Stuart's comment directly below, here is code with GCRS frame and obstime included:

```py
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, GCRS
from astropy import units as u

obs_date = '2019-10-11 00:00'
h = ( -0.217732049,  -2.230749006,  -0.848768038 ) #Skybot cartesian
Skybot_radec = '16 25 19.6257   -19 37 54.618'


helio = SkyCoord(x = h[0],   y =  h[1],  z = h[2],
                               unit='AU',
                               frame = 'icrs',
                               representation_type='cartesian',
                               obstime = obs_date)

geo = helio.transform_to(GCRS(obstime = obs_date))

print('\nFlora\nAstropy =    ', geo.to_string('hmsdms'))
print ('Skybot  =    ', Skybot_radec )

## calculate object separation in the sky
Skybot_radec  = SkyCoord(Skybot_radec, frame = 'gcrs', unit = (u.hourangle, u.deg),
             obstime = obs_date)         
print('separation is ',Skybot_radec.separation(geo))
```

the result is:

```py
Flora
Astropy =     16h20m00.3151s -19d17m49.5591s
Skybot  =     16 25 19.6257     -19 37 54.618
separation is  1d17m53.9205s
```

Much closer but still a significant difference. Any suggestions to get it closer?

Comment: It’s to do with what the origin of your coordinate system is. The RA and Dec returned by Skybot are in a system centred on the observer (which for an observer code of 500 is the center of the Earth). 

If you create a Skycoord in astropy without specifying the coordinate system, the default is ICRS, whose origin is at the Barycentre.

To match the Skybot RA and Dec you should convert your SkyCoord to the GCRS frame, with the obstime attribute set to the same time you used in the Skybot query.

Comment: Stuart, thanks. I did try initially with different frames and observation times included.  It certainly gets the result closer.
I added an example to my question.  Why though does the Jupiter result turn out exact without those inputs to the code?

Comment: Hard to get much closer as Skybot gives geocentric *astrometric* positions. The position of Flora is where it was when the light that reaches us at 2019-10-11 00:00 was emitted. Astropy assumes no space motion of the source, but includes aberration and light deflection. To get closer you'd have to write your own frame transform, based on this [code](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/coordinates/builtin_frames/icrs_cirs_transforms.py#L121), but using ERFA's [atciq](https://github.com/liberfa/erfa/blob/7cc86ae7924669806e5c5de2af08df09b625ea6c/src/atciq.c) not atciqz!

Comment: The answer for Jupiter is much closer, since the motion of Jupiter on the sky is much slower than the asteroids...

Comment: I would have expected that light travel time, astrometric positions etc. would only be worth arcseconds or at most a minute or two worth of the difference.

Comment: Flora moves through the sky at the same order of magnitude as Jupiter, tens of arc second an hour.  I can get exact solutions for Mars and Venus using the simplest code in my question, and they are both moving quicker than Flora. Maybe Skybot calculates the heliocentric vectors for the asteroids differently and it is not accurate?  Seems unlikely but I guess I will contact them and see.